# VBA script for Incremental labeling in Field Calculator?

Tags: vba

I have a shape file with a bunch of pipes in it.  I would like to be able to label each pipe with "Pipe - X".  X being the number in the row that the pipe falls on (Pipe - 1, Pipe - 2, Pipe - 3, etc).

I've tried using a for loop VBA Script for this but it doesn't work.  The VBA script is as follows:

For counter = 1 To 192
Y = "Pipe - " & counter
Next counter

Pipe_ID = Y

My result is "Pipe - 192"

Any Ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to identify which software are you using so people can answer this better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a static variable to keep track of the incremental value (assuming you're using ArcGIS) in thei field calculator (toggle on the 'advanced' tab)

```
Static cnt As Integer
Dim startValue as Integer
Dim result as Integer
startValue = 192
cnt = cnt + 1
result = cnt + startValue
```

then, whateveryourfieldnameis="Pipe-" & result

I think that should work

Comment: Wolfodrade,

That code did the trick.  I had to modify it just a bit to get the labels to start at 1:


Static cnt As Integer

Dim startValue as Integer

Dim result as Integer

startValue = 0

cnt = cnt + 1

result = cnt + startValue

Thanks Alot!

Comment: Good to hear! Sorry I thought you were starting at 192. Now, can you a) please comment on MY message, b)give a point, c) choose my answer as the 'selected', and d) delete your answer here? The answers are for answers, not comments :-)  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting Y to a new value in each iteration of the loop, but not retrieving it until after the loop completes.   Have you tried:

```
For Counter = 1 To 192
  Y = "Pipe - " & counter
  Pipe_ID = Y
 Next counter
```

Answer (score 0):

"Pipe-" &RIGHT ("00"&result,2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but I would just make a Label expression like this:
"Pipe - " & [OBJECTID].

I think that it would work - and you would always get unique labels.